# Using existing R model in Qlik Sense

Tags: r, qliksense

I am using Qlik Sense as a visualization tool. I have Integrated R with it using SSE.  I wanted to ask if I can use existing R model which I have built and saved in my local disk for prediction using Qlik Sense

Answer (score 0):

Yes - when you call R from Qlik Sense, you can load the saved model as you would do in a normal R session.